# Replace ZFS in use hot spare

Tags: linux, zfs, zfsonlinux

Here is the current status of my zpool

```
NAME                                          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
store                                         ONLINE       0     0     0
  mirror-0                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
    ata-WDC_WD20EARX-00PASB0_WD-WCAZAE876073  ONLINE       0     0     0
    ata-ST3000DM001-1ER166_Z5039XGZ           ONLINE       0     0     0
  mirror-1                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
    ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WCC4N0NLY6U6  ONLINE       0     0     0
    ata-ST3000VN007-2AH16M_ZGY6SD1W           ONLINE       0     0     0
  mirror-2                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
    ata-ST3000DM008-2DM166_Z505833Z           ONLINE       0     0     0
    ata-ST3000DM008-2DM166_Z505820B           ONLINE       0     0     5
  mirror-3                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
    ata-WDC_WD30EZRX-00D8PB0_WD-WMC4N1218599  ONLINE       0     0     0
    ata-ST3000DM001-1ER166_W501PFFA           ONLINE       0     0     0
spares
  ata-ST3000VN007-2AH16M_ZGY6SD1W             INUSE     currently in use
```

The spare `ZGY6SD1W` is in use in `mirror-1`. The disk it replaced is nowhere to be seen. It is not listed in `zdb` either. I have another disk to add to the pool, so I can either `1)` make the current spare take its place in `mirror-1` permanently, and use the new disk as a new spare, or `2)`, add the new disk  to `mirror-1`, letting `ZGY6SD1W` go back to being an available spare.

Which doesn't matter to me, but how can I safely progress here? What I've seen from manpages/examples involves issuing `replace` or `detach` commands on the faulty drive, but I have no faulty drive to reference here. Running a `replace` command on the hot spare *might* get me what I want, but I'd prefer to not *try* stuff on a live system.

This is zfsonlinux 2.0.5